# Que puede ser ?Advertencia: mail (): no se pudo conectar al servidor de correo en el puerto 25 "localhost",)

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin, php7

> Advertencia: mail (): no se pudo conectar al servidor de correo en el puerto 25 "localhost", verifique su configuración "SMTP" y "smtp_port" en php.ini o use ini_set ()

```
    $cabecera="From: TickenSystem Venezuela<TickenSystem@gmail.com>";
    $mensaje_mail="Estimado usuario la solución a su problema es la siguiente : ".$solucion_edit;
    $mensaje_mail=wordwrap($mensaje_mail, 70, "\r\n");

    if(MysqlQuery::Actualizar("ticket", "estado_ticket='$estado_edit', solucion='$solucion_edit'", "id='$id_edit'")){

        echo '
            <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade in col-sm-3 animated bounceInDown" role="alert" style="position:fixed; top:70px; right:10px; z-index:10;"> 
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="text-center">TICKET Actualizado</h4>
                <p class="text-center">
                    El ticket fue actualizado con exito
                </p>
            </div>
        ';
        if($radio_email=="option2"){
            mail($email_edit, $asunto_edit, $mensaje_mail, $cabecera);
        }

    }else{
        echo '
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in col-sm-3 animated bounceInDown" role="alert" style="position:fixed; top:70px; right:10px; z-index:10;"> 
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="text-center">OCURRIÓ UN ERROR</h4>
                <p class="text-center">
                    No hemos podido actualizar el ticket
                </p>
            </div>
        '; 
    }
}     


$id = MysqlQuery::RequestGet('id');
$sql = Mysql::consulta("SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE id= '$id'");
$reg=mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

?>[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Tú intentas enviar el correo desde tu dominio, o desde localhost? Indica cómo está este apartado `[mail function]` en tu `php.ini`.

Comment: Como te cuenta A. Cedano, seguramente la instalación de PHP en tu servidor tiene, o bien la función mail desactivada, o quizá el equipo donde tienes instalado el webserver está capado por algún tipo de firewall, antivirus o tiene el puerto 25 cerrado